# Ext.Store returning wrong record

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've got an ExtJS Store that works as a codelist and contains records with the attributes **label** and **value**. Moreover, I've got a grid column whose column renderer uses the store's method *findRecord(field, value)* looks up the values in the store and then displays the corresponding label:

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view){
  var columnName = view.panel.columns[colIndex].name;
  var display = value;
  if(columnName){
    var clString = "cl_t_cl_" + columnName; 
    var cl = Ext.getStore(clString);
    if(cl){
      var rec = cl.findRecord("value", value);
      display = rec ? rec.get("label") : value;
    }
  } else if(record.get("label") !== undefined) {
    display = record.get("label");
  }
  return display;
}
```

However, in certain cases the wrong labels are displayed in the grid. For example if I have two records (9, 'Label A') and (99, 'Label B') the grid will display 'Label B' for a raw value of 9.

My first guess was that the value is looked up token by token and that the label is returned as soon as the search token is found in the value of a record, no matter whether it matches exactly (i.e., that the first 9 of 99 would satisfy the search procedure so that it returns the corresponding record). However, the same store is assigned to a combobox which shows the correct label for the same value.

This behaviour is confusing me and I'm wondering why the column renderer fails to look up the correct label while the combobox doesn't. Much more I want to fix this issue but do not know what might cause the issue. Is there anything I'm missing about Ext.Store that would explain this strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which version of ExtJS you use, but the sixth parameter to [`findRecord`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-findRecord) is `exactMatch` since at least ExtJS 4.2. If you set that parameter to true, it should work.

```
var rec = cl.findRecord("value", value, undefined, undefined, undefined, true);
```

Comment: Thank you! I just found it myself a few minutes ago, maybe I should have read the documentation more concisely...